# How to know when UIimageView finished loading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uikit, uiimageview

In my view controller, how can I know when a certain UIImageView has finished loading (large jpeg from documents directory)? I need to know so that I can then swap a placeholder low-res imageview with this hi-res imageview. Do I need to create a custom callback to know this? Any way is fine.

By the way, here is a snippet of code where I load the image:

```
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"hires_%i.jpg", currentPage];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/BookImage/%@", [self documentsDirectory], fileName];
hiResImageView.image = [[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath] autorelease];
```

Comment: Please provide your source code how you load the image.

Comment: Thanks @Tim -- here is some of that source code.

Comment: How large is a 'large jpeg'? Because if you're talking seriously large you'd be much better off using some sort of tiling. There are big performance implications involving UIImageViews and large images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIImageView isn't doing any loading at all. All the loading is being done by `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]`, and your thread is blocked while the file is loaded (so the load is already complete by the time that call finally returns).

What you want to do is something like this:

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString *)filePath {
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadImageInBackground:) withObject:filePath];
}

- (void)loadImageInBackground:(NSString *)filePath {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(didLoadImageInBackground:) withObject:image waitUntilDone:YES];
    [image release];
    [pool release];
}

- (void)didLoadImageInBackground:(UIImage *)image {
    self.imageView.image = image;
}
```

You would set up `self.imageView` to display the low-res image and then call `loadImage:` to load the high-res version.

Note that if you call this repeatedly before `didLoadImageInBackground:` gets called from earlier calls, you may cause the device to run out of memory. Or you might have the image from the first call take so much longer to load than image from the second call that `didLoadImageInBackground:` gets called for the second image before it gets called for the first. Fixing those issues is left as an exercise for the reader (or for another question).

Comment: thanks, great answer. But, is - (void)didLoadImageInBackground:(UIImage *)image guaranteed wait until AFTER the image loading has completed? This is my concern, the actual ordering of tasks at runtime..

Comment: As I said earlier, the image is done loading when `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]` returns.

Comment: Unfortunately `[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath]` is not doing all the loading stuff. It just loads the file into the memory. Much of the process is done when the UIImageView is being drawn (decompression/drawing/RGBA conversion) and unfortunately iOS does not have any delegate or notification such as `imageDidFinishedDrawing`. You can try this by putting a `NSLOG` right after `imageWithContentsOfFile` and you will see that first NSLOG is performed before image being drawn. (choose a big JPEG to test it)